# Using selenium in a node docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium in my nodeJS docker container. My current attempt fails.
I have tried to install selenium in my docker container from nodejs. Unfortunately, I always get this error message. It works on my PC, but not in my container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox-esr

RUN apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
    chmod +x geckodriver && \
    mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"


WORKDIR /api

COPY . .

RUN npm install --production

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Error:

```
/api/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:260
                reject(Error(e.message))
                       ^
Error: Server terminated early with status 2
    at /api/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:260:24
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Node.js v20.2.0
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Soorya Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good solution and switched to PUPPETEER. It has worked perfectly for me ever since.

Comment: this worked for me https://medium.com/@sooryasankar/selenium-nodejs-headless-firefox-google-cloud-run-bc2a2f7886e6